# how can i override simple_form bootstrap style with my bootstrap form styles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i have built ***simple_form*** fields in my railsapp,when i adding ***simple_form***  tag it style get changes, and i want to integrate this simple_form with my alredy built frontend bootstrap forms
this is my

## bootstrap form

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus />
```

## simple_form filed

```
<%= f.input :email,html:{class: "form-control"},required: false,autofocus: true %>
```

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to use { } for bootstrap class.

And there is nothing like **f.input**

```
<%= f.text_field :email,class: 'form-control',required: false,autofocus: true %>
```